# Comparar dos columnas de dos dataframe en R y determinar cuales son las filas diferentes

Tags: r, dataframe, comparaciones

tengo dos dataframe, digamos DF1 y DF", que se parecen a los siguientes:

```
|Symbol |   Date    | volume |price |
|------------------------------------
|A      |2014-01-01 | 1      |   5  |
|A      |2014-01-02 | 3      |   8  |
|A      |2014-01-03 | 7      |   4  |
|A      |2014-01-07 |3       |   6  |
|A      |2014-01-08 |34      |   7  |
|A      |2014-01-09 |45      |  34  |
|A      |2014-01-10 |4       |   5  | 
|A      |2014-01-11 |9       |   7  |
|A      |2014-01-14 |8       |   6  |
|A      |2014-01-15 |4       |   4  |
|A      |2014-01-16 |0       |   7  |
|A      |2014-01-17 |4       |   7  |



|   Date    | returns|
|--------------------
|2014-01-01 | 4      | 
|2014-01-02 | 6      |  
|2014-01-03 | 8      |  
|2014-01-07 | 2      |  
|2014-01-08 | 14     |   
|2014-01-09 | 5      |  
|2014-01-10 | 1      |    
|2014-01-11 | 2      |   
|2014-01-14 |8       |  
|2014-01-15 |4       |  
|2014-01-16 |0       |   
|2014-01-17 |4       |
```

Quisiera encontrar la forma de verificar si todas las filas de la columna date del dataframe df1 son iguales a las correspondientes filas de la columna date del dataframe df2, y de no ser así saber exactamente cuales son las filas diferentes. Un problema puede ser que el dataframe df1 tiene una fila más que el df2.

He intentado con la siguiente línea de código:

```
identical(df1$date,df2$date)
```

Gracias por leer y cualquier sugerencia será de gran ayuda

Answer (score 0):

`identical()` solo identifica si dos objetos son exactamente iguales, por lo tanto solo devuelve un unico booleano. Podria utilizarse`%in%`, que tiene la ventaja de que funciona con objetos de distinto tamaño.

```
##vector 1 , longitud=16
date1=c("01/01/2014", "19/05/2014","03/10/2014","05/07/2014",
         "01/27/2014","10/01/2014","16/11/2014","02/01/2014" ,"03/01/2014" ,"07/01/2014",
        "08/01/2014","09/01/2014","11/01/2014","14/01/2014",
        "15/01/2014","16/01/2014")
##vector 2, longitud=12
date2=c("01/01/2014","02/01/2014","03/01/2014","07/01/2014","08/01/2014",
          "09/01/2014","10/01/2014","11/01/2014","14/01/2014","15/01/2014",
          "16/01/2014","17/01/2014")

##identical  regresa solo un boleano
identical(date1, date2)
[1] FALSE

## x %in% y regresa un vector de booleanos de la misma longitud que x 
date1 %in% date2
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[14]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

##podemos utilizar esto para extraer los valores distintos

date1[date1 %in% date2==FALSE]
[1] "19/05/2014" "03/10/2014" "05/07/2014" "01/27/2014" "16/11/2014"
```

Answer (score 0):

Si los dataframe tienen pocas filas, tal vez resulte más fácil de verificar viendo las fechas de ambos DF lado a lado.

```
# Dataframes con 12 y 11 filas
Fecha1=c("01/01/2014", "02/01/2014","03/01/2014","07/01/2014",
        "08/01/2014","09/01/2014","10/01/2014","11/01/2014" ,"14/01/2014" ,"15/01/2014",
        "16/01/2014","17/01/2014")
Symbol1 = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A")

Fecha2=c("01/01/2014", "02/02/2014","03/01/2014","07/01/2014",
        "08/01/2014","09/01/2014","10/02/2014","11/02/2014" ,"14/01/2014" ,"15/01/2014",
        "16/01/2014")
Symbol2 = c("B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")

DF1= data.frame(Symbol1,Fecha1)
DF2= data.frame(Symbol2,Fecha2)

# Se agrega una fila vacía al DF2, para que ambos DF tengan la misma cantidad de filas.
DF2 <-add_row(DF2,Symbol2=NA,Fecha2=NA)

# Se crea un dataframe a partir de DF1 y DF2, con una columna en que se comparan las fechas.
DF_comparacion <- cbind(DF1,DF2) %>% 
# Union de los dataframe
  select(Fecha1,Fecha2)%>% 
# Selección de las columnas de interes
  mutate(Comparacion_fechas = ifelse(Fecha1==Fecha2,"Igual","Distinta")) 
# Creación de una columna en que se indica si las fechas en la misma fila son iguales
```

Al visualizar el dataframe combinado (DF_comparacion %>% view()) se puede identificar fácilmente cuáles filas tienen fechas diferentes. Y también se podría usar un filtro para seleccionar concretamente las filas en que las fechas son diferentes

```
DF_comparacion %>% filter(Comparacion_fechas=="Distinta")
```